# Relativistic Doppler Effect of light

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

Is the formula of the non-relativistic doppler effect of light a limiting case of the relativistic doppler effect?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SE. Just as a reminder, if an answer solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: it describes the limit of what happens when $v \ll c$. You can get it by retaining only the lowest order term in $v/c$ in the full formula.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot